# separating user input number with spaces

Tags: c#

I need to separate the number that the user inputs (up to five digits) with three spaces in between. So if the user inputs the number 12345, then the console prints out, "1   2   3   4   5".

I just have the console printing out the number:

```
class MainClass  
{  
    public static void Main (string[] args)  
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Please enter in a five digit number: ");  
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine ();  
        Console.WriteLine (userInput);  
        Console.ReadKey ();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is an obvious homework problem with no attempted solution

Comment: What have you been taught about getting individual characters from a string?

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter in a five digit number: ");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray()));
    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hımmm, It looks like a homework ;)

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a five digit number: ");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

for (int i = 0; i < userInput.Length; i++) {
 char[] ip = userInput.ToCharArray();
 Console.Write(ip[i] + "   ");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a five digit number: ");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

foreach(char c in userInput) {
 Console.Write(c + "   ");
}
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a five digit number: ");
        string num = Console.ReadLine();
        string result = "";
        foreach (char n in num)
        {
            result += n + "   ";
        }
        Console.Write(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick for you :)

```
class MainClass
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Please enter in a five digit number: ")
    string answer = string.Empty;
    int userInput = 0;

    for(int i = 0, i < 5, i++)
    {
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        // Append 3 spaces to each input provided by the user
        answer = string.Format("{0}{1}{3}",answer, userInput, "   ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(answer)
}
```

Comment: You clearly didn't test this code. Or read the question. Where do you get 3 spaces as a requirement?

Comment: Have you tested `string userInput[5] = Console.ReadLine();`?

Comment: Sorry i was on my phone and went a bit quick, i edited it and now it should work

Comment: The user should only be inputting a single string that you then need to parse into individual digits. There's still something wrong with your string.Format() also.